# MySQL Data in the PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table as follows that is used to store details of employees:

```
+---------+---------+------------------+
| of_code |  name   | employment_status |
+---------+---------+------------------+
|       1 | Jhon    |                1 |
|       2 | Ram     |                1 |
|       3 | Edward  |                3 |
|       4 | William |                2 |
+---------+---------+------------------+
```

This is one of the options in my Codeigniter project.

## Desired output

I want to show the employment_status in separate columns in the view as per the value in it. If employment_status = 1, it should be in the first column. If employment_status = 2, it should be in the second column. If employment_status = 3, it should be in the the column and so on.

## Controller (Relevant Part)

```
$where = NULL;
$this->data['officerList'] = $this->Officer_model->officerSummary($where);
```

## Model

```
function officerSummary($where){
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT 
    of_code, name, employment_status as cnt 
    from tbl_officer $where     

    ");
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();

        }
    }
```

## View (Relevant Part)

```
<?php
$officerLists = [];
foreach ($officerList as $row) {
    if (!in_array($row->cnt, $officerLists)) {
        $officerLists[] = $row->cnt;
    }
}
?>

<div class="table-responsive" id="datatable">

                <table id="ExData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                       class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped reports-table">
                    <thead id="th">
                    <tr class="" style="background-color: #d966ff !important;">
                        <th>#</th>

                        <th style width="5%" class="text-center"><font size="1"> Code</th>
                        <th style width="15%" class="text-left"><font size="1">Name</th>                                
                        <th class="text-center" colspan="<?= count($officerLists) ?>"><font size="1">Employment Status</th>         

                    </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <?php

                    $count = [];                   
                    if(!empty($officerList)) {
                        foreach ($officerList as $rows) {
                            $total += $rows->cnt;

                            $c++;
                            ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td><font size="1"><?= $rows->of_code ?></td>
                                <td><?= $rows->name ?></td>                               

                                <?php
                                foreach ($officerLists as $value) {
                                if ($rows->cnt == $value) {
                                if (isset($count[$value]))
                                    $count[$value] = $count[$value] + $rows->of_code;
                                else
                                    $count[$value] = $rows->of_code;
                                echo "<td class='text-center'></td>";
                            } else
                                echo "<td class='text-center'>-</td>";                          
                             }                      

                        }

                        ?>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

The function outs three columns correctly, but with no values. Only '-' shows non-relevant places in the column as follows. 
[image: Employment Status]

What may be going wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: You are not closing <tr> used in foreach

Comment: Also, you are just echo `<td class='text-center'></td>` How it will show the value?

Comment: Share a screenshot of the actual output.

Comment: Be careful you have a security vulnerability in your view  `<?= $rows->name ?>`
If a bad employee will call self `<script>alert('Hi, I am a hacker :)') <script>`. On this page, you will get the alert. 
More dangerous if he will read all your cookies and send them to somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a `SELECT - CASE` structure can be your option

A query in this way

```
SELECT of_code,
       name,
       CASE WHEN employment_status = 1 THEN employment_status AS StatusA,
       CASE WHEN employment_status = 2 THEN employment_status AS StatusB,
       CASE WHEN employment_status = 3 THEN employment_status AS StatusC
FROM yourTbale;
```

- Every `CASE` will verify if the status is 1 or 2 or 3
- Th previous step will generate a new column with a given alias
- Because we need the status value as cell value in our result I put it again after the `THEN` clause

If this work, you only will need to adapt it in CI sintax

Comment: @ Aprendiz. I do not need to show the values in a single column. There must be 3 columns. One for 1, another for 2 & another for 3

Comment: Using CASE in  my example will generate three columns

Comment: @ Aprendiz. Ok I will check

Comment: @ Aprendiz. Your CASE is working for one field in the view like StatusA. But there are StatusB & StatusC in the query. How can I show this result in my view. The columns are vary as per employment_status. If there is another status as 4, There will be 4 columns needed

Comment: Send data to your View and iterate it through a foreach to get data through name fields given in the query body

Comment: @ Aprendiz. Can you change my foreach which is mentioned above ?